# Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/ from localhost:4200 to http://localhost:3000 (ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: angular, cors, go

Tengo un servidor en Go con puerto 3000 que contiene una api
y un servidor en Angular con puerto 4200 que la consume,
estoy usando un proxy en Angular que es este:

```
{
    "/api":{
        "target": "http://localhost:3000",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
        
    }
}
```

Modifico el valor del start en package json:

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"
```

Y uso el comando:

```
npm start
```

Pero en el momento de hacer una petición Angular no la hace al  puerto 3000 si no que utiliza la dirección del puerto de angular 4200
y en la consola de angular me genera el siguiente error:

> [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/ from localhost:4200 to http://localhost:3000 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)

Por parte de Go intente habilitar los cors así:

```
func Enrutador() {
    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)

    router.HandleFunc("/", rutaInicial).Methods("GET")
    router.HandleFunc("/cargartienda", cargartienda).Methods("POST")
    router.HandleFunc("/api/TiendaEspecifica", TiendaEspecifica).Methods("POST")
    router.HandleFunc("/api/Eliminar", Eliminar).Methods("POST")
    router.HandleFunc("/api/id/{id}", BusquedaPosicion).Methods("GET")
    fmt.Println("servidor escuchando en puerto : 3000")

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3000", handlers.CORS(handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Authorization"}), handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"}), handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"}))(router)))
}
```

Pero no consigo dar con la solución de este inconveniente.

Comment: Revisa el `/etc/hosts` a ver si posees `127.0.0.1 localhost`, sino cambia `localhost` por `127.0.0.1` en el target. Podría ser, quizá, el problema.

Comment: Lo mejor es agregarlo, algunos paquetes del sistema esperan que se resuelva `localhost` como `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: hice las 2 y no hay solucion

Comment: Hola @Angel, has probado añadiendo `router.Use(mux.CORSMethodMiddleware(router))`  y sustituyendo el `log.Fatal...` por esto `http.ListenAndServe(":3000", router)`. Si funciona avisame que te paso un código con mas detalle.